# Не работает if в цикле for c#

Tags: c#, математика, if, for

Требуется написать цикл, чтобы если текущее число является числом 2 в некой степени, то создается группа, в которую это число записывается.

Код:

```
int n = 50;

int group = 0;

int count = 0; // для проверки, что цикл работает
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    if (i == Math.Pow(2, i - 1))
    {
        group++;

        Console.WriteLine($" Группа{group}: {i}");
    }

        count++;
}
```

Выводится в консоли:

```
Группа 1: 1

Группа 2: 2
```

Цикл отрабатывается, но не могу понять, почему не выводит последующие значения для if

Comment: `если текущее число является числом 2 в некой степени` не в некой степени, а `i == Math.Pow(2, i - 1)`, то есть для числа 8 вы проверите, является ли число 8 двойкой в 7 степени.

Comment: Вы для каждого i проверяете не то, что оно является степенью двойки, а то, что оно равно 2 ^ (i - 1), что действительно верно только для чисел 1 и 2.

Answer (score 2):

Существует известный битовый трюк для проверки, является ли положительное целое число `x` степенью двойки:

```
(x & (x - 1)) == 0
```

Если `x` может быть нулём или отрицательным, то необходимо добавить условие `x > 0`:

```
((x & (x - 1)) == 0) && (x > 0)
```

На английской версии сайта есть [объяснение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19383296/3303996), почему это работает. В итоге, искомый цикл может выглядеть так:

```
int n = 50;
int group = 0;

for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    if ((i & (i - 1)) == 0)
        Console.WriteLine($"Группа {++group}: {i}");
```

Comment: Хм, почему тогда не просто `for (int p = 1; p < n; p *= 2)`?

Comment: @VladD Хорошее замечание. Я предполагал, что в вопросе была указана лишь часть задания и для нестепеней двойки тоже нужно что-то делать. Иначе вопрос («цикл, чтобы если текущее число является числом 2 в некой степени...») следует переформулировать.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Верно, это является частью задания)